# Auth0 - Insufficient scope

Tags: node.js, authentication, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) in my Node.js application and I'm facing **Insufficient scope** error when trying to protect any routes in my app.

I've been searching for a while and I found a bunch of similar problem, but couldn't manage to find the solution.

Essentially, in my node app I have to protect a route as follow:

```
const checkScopes = jwtAuthz(['read:flights']);
```

However, I always receive **Insufficient scope** error when adding the middleware to protect my route:

```
app.get('/api/permission', checkJwt, checkScopes, (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    msg: 'Your access token AND PERMISSION was successfully validated!'
  });
});
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should include a second parameter called "customScopeKey" this way auth0 will use permission instead of scope to validate the user credentials.

use this:

```
const checkScopes = jwtAuthz(['read:flights'], { customScopeKey: "permissions" });
```

instead of

```
const checkScopes = jwtAuthz(['read:flights']);
```

Comment: Can you help with this: I try with your solution, but I have the same result >>>. "WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="Insufficient Scope", scope="read:messages"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"

Answer (score 2):

You can try `const checkScopes = jwtAuthz(['read:flights'], { customUserKey: "auth" });`

By default, permissions are checked against req.user. However, I noticed in the latest version, req.user is undefined. Instead, the token is under req.auth

Comment: This definetly helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have saved my sanity along with my business. God speed you.

Just to reiterate (with example)...

```
app.get('/test', jwtCheck, jwtAuthz(['read:generatedLeads'], { customScopeKey: "permissions", customUserKey: "auth" }),  (req, res) => {
    infoLogger.info(FILE_NAME, METHOD, "Health Check is passing...")
    res.status(200).send({health: "Token Accepted"})
})
```

Adding customUserKey: "auth" as part of the config for jwtAuthz resolved my issue with "insufficient scope" error.